# Using curly braces alone in R to create collapsing code blocks?

Tags: r, curly-braces, rstudio

So, I've been using the RStudio IDE lately, and I really like it. In writing R code, I've been striving to keep it simple and easy to read. However, some of my scripts are just getting a little visually overwhelming, especially when I switch to working on my home computer (1280x1024, vs. 2 1920x1080 panels).

I noticed that RStudio supports collapsing code blocks when the curly brace is used, and I tested surrounding different blocks of code with braces. RStudio promptly indented them for me and then collapsed them upon request. It didn't seem to affect the code at all - still ran just the same.

I know that I could take the code blocks in question and create functions out of them, which might accomplish the same thing (collapse the function), but I was curious if there was any reason why I shouldn't use the curly braces in this way? I know that curly braces have been shown to speed up R computation ([as described here](http://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/two-surpising-things-about-r/)), but I'm not sure how it would affect my programs.

Comment: Curly braces don't speed up computations.  That blog post only showed they're more efficient than parenthesis.  The post is also ~2 years old and used a 3 year old version of R, so it may no longer be true in current versions of R.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Of course, you're correct - I misspoke there. My apologies. :)

Comment: Furthermore, RStudio allows insert code sections, which are comments basically, that allows to collpse code blocks as well.

Comment: The best thing you can do to make you code more readable is to put your code into functions, and put them in a seperate file. At the start of a script you can `source` whatever you need, keeping your script short. A bunch of these files could even be bundled into a package, providing even more abstraction, in addition to the ability to add tests and documentation.

Comment: @LucianoSelzer Wow, didn't even know about that. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Yes, the good programmer in me knows that I should make functions, which I might end up doing, but for the interim this will help the development process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to create collapsable code blocks is to use code sections. The hotkey to create a code section is CRTL + SHIFT + R. An alternative way is to split up your longer script into a number of functions. These functions can also be collapsed.

Comment: No one ever answered, I was hoping someone would type up the code sections part and then I could accept it.

Comment: No problem, it would have been fine for you to take the comments and answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: Duh. Should have thought of that. Will do next time. :)